# TikZ Mindmap: How can I make nodes autosize to fit the text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

How can I have the size of a mindmap node be calculated automatically by TikZ such that the text inside fits nicely inside? With `inner sep=...` I am able to have the height fit in such a way, but not the width. Btw.: I am using rectangles as nodes, not the standard circles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={concept, rectangle, minimum size=0cm, inner sep=2mm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,text=white]
\node {O} child { node {A} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimum working example (MWE). How are we to guess what you've done or how you've configured a non-standard mind map if you don't show us?

Comment: @cfr: I don't quite see the necessity in this case, but here you go.

Comment: Well, it makes it much easier to answer. How else can I know what you've done?

Comment: I like the rectangular style. I never realised you can do this. Does it work with the gradual change of colour in connections between the nodes? I guess it should? I guess it would be nice if the transition to the connection could be smoother, though. It keeps reminding me of Dairy Milk ads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can simply add

```
text width=
```

to the style for `every node`. The `mindmap` style applies styles for each level of the `tree` which set the width of the text. You could override these separately per level, but if you want to do this generally, just adding it for all nodes seems to make more sense.

This produces

[image: shrink-to-fit nodes]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={concept, text width=, rectangle, minimum size=0cm, inner sep=2mm},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,text=white]
  \node {Orangutans} child { node {Aardvarks} child { node {Bees} } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```