# How to auto-arrange nodes of a mindmap in TikZ (to avoid overlapping nodes and connections)

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

There is a library in TikZ for creating mind (or concept) maps (https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#section.60).

However, it doesn't seem that intuitive to use. I want nodes to automatically adjust to their content (which can partly be achieved with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285655/194783).

Additionally, I want the mind map to be arranged (at least semi-)automatically.

So that things like in this MWE don't happen:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
{\centering
    \makebox[0pt]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [mindmap,
            grow cyclic,
            every node/.style={concept, text width=},
            concept color=teal!40,
            ]
            \node {node}
                child{
                    node {subnode}
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                }
                child{
                    node {subnode}
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                }
                child{
                    node {subnode}
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                }
                child{
                    node {subnode}
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                }
                child{
                    node {subnode}
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                }
                child{
                    node {subnode}
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                }
                child{
                    node {subnode}
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                    child { node {subnode} }
                };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \par
}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I assume, in CSS, one defines margins to have non-overlapping elements.

Part of the solution might include setting dynamic sibling angles (like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118746/194783) and defining a custom growth function (as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232914/194783).

Edit:
To mitigate the problem, I added some code to automatically set the `sibling angle` based on the number of children of a node. This still doesn't always avoid overlap, though.

I have seen several posts about writing custom growth functions to achieve a special shape. This also often solves overlaps, but I don't want the shapes that are used there.

- [How to put level 2 concept mindmap nodes alongside a rectangle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232816/how-to-put-level-2-concept-mindmap-nodes-alongside-a-rectangle)
- [Mindmaps, method to get regular circle shape for level 4 or 5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539375/mindmaps-method-to-get-regular-circle-shape-for-level-4-or-5)
- [Grow circular tree with forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574881/grow-circular-tree-with-forest)

For a related problem, there is the `forest` package suggested, which doesn't entirely help in my case: [Overlapping nodes in a tree using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505350/overlapping-nodes-in-a-tree-using-tikz)

Comment: I'm interested in this too, shame there doesn't seem to be much of a solution to this as it would be handy!

I'm guessing there is a solution that could be calculated using a kind of force of attraction and repulsion between nodes, but I'm nowhere near savvy enough to do this with LaTeX.